# London in 2020 with US citizen friends

Tags: schengen-visas, filipino-citizens

I am a green card holder. I am going to France, Spain and Italy with my  US citizen friends.   In addition to my Schengen visa, do I need a separate visa for London?

Comment: Sure. What citizenship do you hold?

Comment: London is not in France, Spain or Italy.  It's also not in the Schengen area as per the  tag.  What exactly is it you're trying to ask?

Comment: Sure you can ask for a visa. What passport do you hold?

Comment: Philippine passport and I’m still waiting for my interview for citizenship within 6moo and i also

Comment: I’m waiting for my interview for citizenship within 6 months and my Philippine passport was stamped by the immigration for extension to travel until August next year.

Comment: I checked online that London is not included in the Schengen visa.  Do i have to ask separate visa for London since thats our main destination?

Comment: London is in the United Kingdom and so if you want to travel there, you have to apply for a UK visa, which as you note is a completely separate process from the Schengen visa.

Answer (score 5):

As a green card holder and Filipino citizen, you will indeed need 2 visas.

-One for your trip within the Schengen area (France, Spain, Italy). The consulate you apply to will be the one representing the country which is your main destination (most days spent) out of these three.

-And another visa from the UK so that you may visit London.

Answer (score 1):

The UK is not in the Schengen area which includes most of Europe. This means that there is passport control and in addition to the Schengen visa you got for France, Spain and Italy you will need one for the UK.

While not official, this website seemed to spell things out quite clearly: https://www.tripzilla.ph/uk-tourist-visa-philippine-passport-holders/748

Comment: I tried to correct the spelling of Italy and add commas.   There is a 6 char minimum for an edit. hmmm.

Comment: @C'estMoi Thanks for that. Fixed!